# Generating Authentication Header

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to generate the authentication header for a third party through not using the PayPal SDK. I have gotten their access token and secret. However these have been through curl requests which have been straightforward to me. Is there anyway to do it like this?

In addition, to generate the header I need an API signature of the third party? how would I get this?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you clarify for which product this is?

Comment: Sure. I'm using 1c Enterprise and how I make the calls are through breaking Curl calls down into HTTPRequests and such. here's an example of how I called for a request token (replaced my API details). In this case, I have to try to obtain the api signature or authentication header in the same way. Sadly this is the limit of what I can do. http://pastebin.com/UWir6t35

Comment: Sorry, I meant the PayPal product. Looking at the paste, I can see you mean the Permissions API.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by product. But I'm trying to get permission to send and create invoices on behalf of the third party. I went through all the guides. and I get to the creation of the access token and secret succesfully. I just get stuck at creating the authentication header. and I was wondering if there was another way besides using the paypal sdk. Like through some curl request.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for a node.js solution to PayPal X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header values, I wrote this:

```
function PayPalURLEncoder(s)
{
    var hex = "0123456789abcdef";
    var untouched = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_";
    var result = s.split('').map(function(c){
        if (untouched.indexOf(c)>=0)    { return c; }
        else if (c==' ')                { return "+"; }
        else
        {
            // Needs converting to HEX
            var code = c.charCodeAt(0);
            return "%" + hex.charAt((code & 0xf0) >> 4) + hex.charAt(code & 0xf);
        }
    });
    return result.join('');
}

exports.authorizationToken = function(accessToken,method,endpoint)
{
    var PARAM_DELIMETER = "&";
    var PARAM_SEPERATOR = "=";
    var token = { key : accessToken.token, secret : accessToken.tokenSecret};
    var consumer = { key : global.config.paypal.username, secret : global.config.paypal.password };

    // Add params
    var params = {
        "oauth_consumer_key" : consumer.key,
        "oauth_version" : "1.0",
        "oauth_signature_method" : "HMAC-SHA1",
        "oauth_token" : token.key,
        "oauth_timestamp" : Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
    };

    // Convert params into paramString
    var paramKeys = [];
    var paramString = "";
    for (var p in params) { paramKeys.push(p); } paramKeys.sort();
    for (var i=0; i<paramKeys.length; i+=1)
    {
        var p = paramKeys[i];
        paramString += (p + PARAM_SEPERATOR + params[p]);
        if (i+1<paramKeys.length) paramString += PARAM_DELIMETER;
    }

    // Create signature
    var key = PayPalURLEncoder(consumer.secret) + PARAM_DELIMETER + PayPalURLEncoder(token.secret);
    var signatureBase = method + PARAM_DELIMETER + PayPalURLEncoder(endpoint) + PARAM_DELIMETER + PayPalURLEncoder(paramString);
    var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signatureBase, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    return "token="+token.key+",signature="+signature+",timestamp="+params["oauth_timestamp"];
};
```

AuthToken is returned from a call to "/Permissions/GetAccessToken" using the usual methods and contains a token and tokenSecret pair for operating on behalf of a third party. Method would be POST and the end point would be something like "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData".

Using the method above might look something like this:

```
exports.basicDetails = function(accessToken, callback)
{
    var http = require('https');
    var host = global.config.paypal.sandbox ? 'svcs.sandbox.paypal.com' : 'svcs.paypal.com';
    var path = '/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData';
    var options = {
        host: host,
        path: path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION" : exports.authorizationToken(accessToken,"POST","https://"+host+path),
            "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" : "NV",
            "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" : "JSON",
            "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" : global.config.paypal.sandbox ? "<<YOURAPPIDSANDBOX>>" : "<<YOURAPPID>>",
        },
    };
    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        var str = "";
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) { str += chunk; });
        res.on('end', function () {
            if (callback) callback(false,JSON.parse(str));
        });
    });
    req.on('error',function(e){
        if (callback) callback("Unable to connect with PayPal");
    });
    req.end("attributeList.attribute(0)=http://axschema.org/contact/email&attributeList.attribute(1)=http://schema.openid.net/contact/fullname&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code shared by Aku, I have ported it over to Python. Unfortunately, this is still leading to an authentication failure response with error code 10002. FWIW, here it is:

```
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
from base64 import b64encode
from urllib import urlencode
from datetime import datetime

def paypal_urlencode(s):
    encode = lambda x: x if x in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_+" else '%%%x' % ord(x)
    return ''.join(map(encode, s.replace(' ','+')))

def paypal_authorisation(token, ep, consumer, method="POST", sandbox=True):
    params = dict(
        oauth_consumer_key=consumer['key'],
        oauth_version='1.0',
        oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_token=token['key'],
        oauth_timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%s')
    )
    key = "&".join((paypal_urlencode(consumer['secret']), paypal_urlencode(token['secret'])))
    sig_base = "&".join((method, paypal_urlencode(ep), paypal_urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=%(oauth_consumer_key)s&oauth_signature_method=%(oauth_signature_method)s&oauth_timestamp=%(oauth_timestamp)s&oauth_token=%(oauth_token)s&oauth_version=%(oauth_version)s" % params)))
    h= hmac.new(key.encode('ascii'), sig_base.encode('ascii'), sha1)
    signature=b64encode(h.digest())

    return "token=%s,signature=%s,timestamp=%s" % (token['key'], signature, params['oauth_timestamp'])
```