# How to generate the X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header in Paypal with the Access Token once third-party permissions are granted?

Tags: python, paypal

After being granted third-party permissions by obtaining the Access Token (token:xxxxxx and tokenSecret:xxxxxxx) using the Paypal's Permissions API as per https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/, I am not having success in following up with other API calls on behalf of the third-party as it is not clear how the X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header should be generated.

Based on sample node.js code written in another SO question: [Generating Authentication Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976860/generating-authentication-header/28820485#28820485), I have done a Python port

```
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
from base64 import b64encode
from urllib import urlencode
from datetime import datetime

def paypal_urlencode(s):
    encode = lambda x: x if x in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_+" else '%%%x' % ord(x)
    return ''.join(map(encode, s.replace(' ','+')))

def paypal_authorisation(token, ep, consumer, method="POST", sandbox=True):
    params = dict(
        oauth_consumer_key=consumer['key'],
        oauth_version='1.0',
        oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_token=token['key'],
        oauth_timestamp=datetime.now().strftime('%s')
    )
    key = "&".join((paypal_urlencode(consumer['secret']), paypal_urlencode(token['secret'])))
    sig_base = "&".join((method, paypal_urlencode(ep), paypal_urlencode("oauth_consumer_key=%(oauth_consumer_key)s&oauth_signature_method=%(oauth_signature_method)s&oauth_timestamp=%(oauth_timestamp)s&oauth_token=%(oauth_token)s&oauth_version=%(oauth_version)s" % params)))
    h= hmac.new(key.encode('ascii'), sig_base.encode('ascii'), sha1)
    signature=b64encode(h.digest())

    return "token=%s,signature=%s,timestamp=%s" % (token['key'], signature, params['oauth_timestamp'])
```

However, I am getting an authentication error code 10002. Appreciate any suggestions in debugging this. Note that the Access Token was successfully received.

Answer (score 0):

From the PayPal Developer documentation:

[PayPal API Error Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)
Error Code 1000:

> This error can be caused by an incorrect API username, an incorrect API password, or an invalid API signature. Make sure that all three of these values are correct. For your security, PayPal does not report exactly which of these three values might be in error.

Make certain that you are using the correct credentials (client id, client secret must be included). If you are in sandbox mode you need to make certain that the credentials you are using are from a business Pro Sandbox Account. If you are in live mode, make certain you are using your live PayPal Credentials.

This sample comes directly from the PayPal Developer site:
[Complete Integration Guide for Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/)

```
Request Sample
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
-u "<Client-Id>:<Secret>" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

For Rest API here are the authentication and headers you should be using: 
[Authentication and Headers Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#authentication--headers)

Client Credentials are found in the Rest API Application you submitted on the PayPal Developer Site. 
Just in case you need it, here is the link to making your first API call it includes creating a Rest API Application: 
[PayPal Rest API Making your first call](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)

Comment: Thanks but as the AccessToken was successfully received after a third-party permission grant, it appears that the issue may be with the formation of the API signature rather than the other two credentials. The question is is the API signature generation methodology correct? Are there any ways to test this independently with a third-party permission authentication?

Comment: Have you succeeded here? I'm stuck on doing this as well, but for .NET. The documentation says you need to generate the signature, but doesn't show any documentation on how to do it. Also the support people don't seem capable of giving the answer either.

Comment: When you create a Rest API App on developer.paypal.com in the dashboard under My Apps & Credentials, if you click on your app it will list your Client ID & Client Secret. If you just need Sandbox API Credentials you can click on Accounts under Sandbox and then click on the Account, then Profile. In the Profile is a tab for API Credentials.

Comment: You can test with third party permissions authentication, but you still need the Client ID and Client Secret in Rest API. Here is information on the [authentication and headers](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/auth-headers/)